# Flask finds the template, but the page output is empty

Tags: flask

[enter image description here][1]I'm doing an APP in flask for a confectionery, in the 'render_template', it finds the file 'home.html', but the output in the browser is empty.

Código Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    nome = "John Doe"
    produtos = ["Bolo de Chocolate", "Cupcake de Baunilha", "Torta de Morango"]
    return render_template('home.html', nome=nome, produtos=produtos)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Saída Navegador:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Template html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minha Página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bem-vindo(a), {{ nome }}!</h1>
    <p>Aqui estão alguns produtos disponíveis:</p>
    <ul>
        {% for produto in produtos %}
        <li>{{ produto }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Directory order in VScode:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAg7C.png

Comment: Please share the template.

Comment: added the question.

Comment: SOLVED!!! The problem was that it wasn't saving the HTML file inside VScode, a simple error. Thank you :)))